# new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3; - как работает эта строчка кода?

Tags: linux, c

Сначала покажу код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>

static struct termios stored_settings;

void set_keypress(void)
{
    struct termios new_settings;

    tcgetattr(0,&stored_settings);

    new_settings = stored_settings;

    new_settings.c_lflag &= (~ICANON);
 //  new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;

    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&new_settings);
    return;
}

void reset_keypress(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0,TCSANOW,&stored_settings);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    set_keypress();
   // char m[5];
    printf("Test: ");

        // putchar здесь вызывается для того, чтобы проверить 
  //  работоспособность
        gets(); 

    reset_keypress();
    return 0;
}
```

Строка `new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;` указывает максимальное количество символов(байтов), которые я могу передать куда-то? Просто я не понял что она делает.

Как я понял, я строкой `new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;` установил ограничение введенных мной символов.Распишу что я не понял еще:

---

1. Так как я включил неканонический режим и поставил ограничение на 3 байта, то больше я ввести не могу. Но на фото видно что я передаю терминалу больше чем три символа[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему я ввел `lllllllllllllllll`, `\n` и `l`? Терминал сосчитал `lllllllllllllllll`за 1 байт что-ли? 
 Также если я введу `ll` и нажму ENTER(\n) то все завершится корректно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Можете не отвечать, чисто из интереса написал этот вопрос, но как убрать факт нажатия клавиши BACKSPACE в неканоническом режиме, просто если я нажимаю эту клавишу то передается код этой клавиши `^?`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Буду очень благодарен если объясните что делает строка `new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;` и ещё одна строчка `new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим *man 3 tcsetattr*:

> VMIN   Минимальное количество символов для неканонического чтения (MIN).
>
> VTIME  Время ожидания в децисекундах для неканонического чтения (TIME).

Используемый "по умолчанию" в ОС UNIX режим ввода данных с клавиатуры терминала называется каноническим. Он подразумевает присутствие между клавиатурой терминала и прикладной программой очереди вводимых символов. Символы нажатых клавиш накапливаются в этой очереди до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмет клавишу "Ввод" (Enter), и только в этот момент осуществляется передача строки накопленных символов в прикладную программу. Выданный в прикладной программе запрос на чтение с клавиатуры (посредством системного вызова read) приостанавливает выполнение программы до момента нажатия клавиши "Ввод".

Для некоторых прикладных программ (редакторов экранных форм, игр и т.п.) такой способ работы с клавиатурой неудобен. Поэтому ОС UNIX предоставляет разнообразные и гибкие средства для управления вводом с клавивтуры (в более широком смысле - асинхронными портами ЭВМ). Один из способов обеспечения "мгновенного" ввода кода символа с клавиатуры (без организации очереди символов, замыкаемой клавишой "Ввод") называется   *неканоническим вводом*.

http://www.igce.comcor.ru/non_canon.html

Comment: Так вы на вопрос то не ответили

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич На самом деле - ответил. Просто если ковырять дальше, то там придётся разбираться "железными" вопросами. Грубо говоря, запрос ввода с терминала висит на *select* и эти параметры указывают драйверу, как себя вести. Ведь терминалом ввода может быть не только клавиатура, но и последовательный порт и другое аналогичное оборудование. 

Короче... Для обычной клавиатуры я использовал значение 0 для обеих этих параметров.